# Differents posts template in a wordpress loop with $count

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, count

I try to have differents templates in my category.php loop with Wordpress.

Here's my code :

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- article -->

<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>

<!--my code for news 1 -->

<?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>
<!--my code for news 2 -->

<?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>
<!--my code for news 3 -->
```

everything works fine, but how I achieve to have not a single number but a range of post. 
Example :

```
$count == 2 > 4
```

I want that the second, third and forth post have the same template for example.

Thank you,

Comment: I think you're looking for `if ( $count >= 2 && $count <= 4 )` which matches 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: @sally CJ I tried your solution, but it doesn't show anypost... Maybe I made a mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code updated with Emma's answer. That works perfectly !

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- article -->

<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>

<!--my code for news 1 -->

<?php elseif ($count > 1 and $count < 5) : ?> 
<!--my code for news 2 -->

<?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>
<!--my code for news 3 -->
```